# Automatically appending ffmpeg directory to path whenever exe is opened?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote a program compiled as an exe, which live on a network drive for other users to use. An issue I'm running into is that for other users (whose machines dont have python installed, not sure if this matters), it states that it can't find ffmpeg:

[image]

I've placed the bin folder of ffmpeg to the same location as the exe, but its not really viable for me to manually go to each users computers to add `\drive\VoiceGen\bin` to their user Path. Is there a way to have the program automatically add the bin location to the userpath?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that I got to work if anyone else is using `pydub`. In `utils.py` under the `which()` method, add `envdir_list.append(\path\to\ffmpeg_on_network_drive)`.